# What is a simple way to let a command run for 5 minutes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

Is there an easy way to let a specific command (only terminable through `Ctrl-C`) run for 5 minutes automatically?

For example:

```
minute-command 5-minutes ping www.google.com
```

or any other command that does not terminate itself.

I'd like to be able to specify a time limit, not only 5 minutes.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There are (at least) two programs that provide this functionality:

> #### NAME
>
> `timelimit` — effectively limit the absolute execution time of a process
>
> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> `timelimit [-pq] [-S killsig] [-s warnsig] [-T killtime] [-t warntime] command [arguments ...]`

and

> #### NAME
>
> `timeout` - run a command with a time limit
>
> #### SYNOPSIS
>
> `timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...`
>   `timeout [OPTION]`

They are packaged as follows:

```
$ dlocate `which timeout timelimit`
timelimit: /usr/bin/timelimit
coreutils: /usr/bin/timeout
```

#### Comparison:

```
/-----------------------------+------------+----------------\
|            Feature          |  timelimit |     timeout    |
+=============================+============+================+
|   time to run               | -t time    | first argument |
+-----------------------------+------------+----------------+
|   terminate signal          | -s signal  | -s signal      |
+-----------------------------+------------+----------------+
|   grace period              | -T time    | -k time        |
+-----------------------------+------------+----------------+
|   kill signal               | -S signal  | (note 1)       |
+-----------------------------+------------+----------------+
|   propagate signals         | -p         | (note 2)       |
\-----------------------------+------------+----------------/
```

Notes:

1. `timeout` always uses `SIGKILL` as its last-resort signal.
2. `timeout` does not have any functionality to exit with a signal when the child program does so.

The exit status of the two programs differ, but that's hard to summarise neatly, so I suggest you consult the manual pages yourself for that.

As `timeout` is installed on more systems by default (`coreutils` is a standard package in many distributions), I suggest you use that unless you need the extra functionality provided by `timelimit`.

Comment: Why would you use one rather than the other?

Comment: @BriceM.Dempsey On my local machine, timeout is present, but timelimit is not (although it is available from the repo). So, if one of them comes pre-installed... Apart from that, just looking at the method signatures I can see that they do different things, and have different use cases.

Comment: Note that there exist at least two implementations of `timelimit`. See [How can I kill a process and be sure the PID hasn't been reused](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181028) for more info on them and GNU timeout.

Comment: @BriceM.Dempsey `timeout` is included in GNU [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), [`timelimit`](http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/) is not. You can have installed none, one or both. For the second it is reported _timelimit executes a command and terminates the spawned process after a given time with a given signal. __A “warning” signal is sent first__, then, after a timeout, a “kill” signal, similar to the way init(8) operates on shutdown._ So even a different _in the middle_ behaviour.

Comment: Since GNU coreutils is preinstalled on every GNU/Linux, `timeout` is the way to go there.

Comment: @rexkogitans, I've edited my answer to address your comments.

Comment: can any of these programs kill the whole process tree (like, `kill -TERM -1234` kills PID 1234 and its children)

Comment: Not as far as I know, @törzsmókus - you'll need to modify one of the tools, or perhaps write a small wrapper program that catches signals and then re-signals its own process group.  Of course, that has limitations, given that KILL and STOP are uncatchable.

Comment: thx @TobySpeight! I wonder then how can `kill -TERM -1234` _just work™_…

Comment: @törzsmókus - no, that bit's fine; what you can't do is write a program that *handles* those signals - it will be stopped before it's able to then kill its process group.  Try it in Bash:  `trap 'kill -KILL -$$' KILL` for example.  (Of course, doing the same thing with SIGTERM *is* possible - it's only STOP and KILL that are uncatchable).

Answer (score 87):

Actually, this is what `timeout` is for:

```
TIMEOUT(1)                          User Commands                         TIMEOUT(1)

NAME
       timeout - run a command with a time limit

SYNOPSIS
       timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
       timeout [OPTION]

DESCRIPTION
       Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

lx@lxtp:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/timeout
coreutils: /usr/bin/timeout
```

Answer (score 18):

### Pure `bash` built in, without *coreutils*

I found that this solution works in `bash` relying on a *built-in* command without calling an external executable. It works on system where eventually are not even been installed the *coreutils* <sup>[[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)]</sup>

```
YourCommand & read -t 300 ;  kill $!                           # 1st version
YourCommand & read -t 300 || kill $!                           # 2nd version
```

**Explanations**: as usual when you send a command in the background with `&`, its PID is stored into the internal variable `$!` (present in the modern version of `dash`, `csh`, `bash`, `tcsh`, `zsh`...).
What really makes the difference among the shells is the presence of the *built-in* command `read`<sup>[[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)]</sup> and of the option `-t`. 
In the 1st version if the user will not complete a line of input before the specified amount of seconds the instruction will be terminated and an error return code will be generated.

> <sup>**-t TIMEOUT**  Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not read within TIMEOUT seconds.</sup>

The second version works as the 1st but you can abort the killing timeout just pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.
Indeed the or operator `||` executes the `kill` statement only if the `read` command exits with a return code different from zero, as when the timeout is expired. If you press <kbd>enter</kbd> before that moment, it will return 0 and it will not kill your previous command.

---

### Coreutils solutions <sup>[[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)]</sup>

When *coreutils* are present on your system and you have no need to save the time and the resources to call an external program,  `timeout` and `sleep` and are both perfect ways to reach your goal.

**`timeout`** The use of `timeout` is straightforward.
Eventually you can consider to use also the `-k` option to send an additional kill signal if the first fails.

```
timeout 5m YourCommand                                         # 3rd version
```

**`sleep`**
With `sleep` you can use your fantasy or take some inspirations<sup>[[3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)]</sup>. Note that you can leave your command in background or in foreground (e.g. `top` usually needs to be in foreground).

```
YourCommand & sleep 5m; kill $!                                # 4th Background
YourCommand & pid=$! ; (sleep 5m; kill $pid;) &                # 5th Background

bash -c '(sleep 5m; kill $$) & exec YourCommand'               # 6th Foreground
(cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep 5m; kill $cmdpid) & exec YourCommand) # 7th Foreground
```

**Explanations**

- <sup>In the 4th version you execute in background `YourCommand` then  your shell `sleep`s for 5 minuites. When it will be finished the last background process (`$!`) will be killed. You stop your shell.</sup>
- <sup>In the 5th version instead you execute in background `YourCommand` and you store immediately that PID in the variable `$pid`. Then you execute in background a *nap* of 5 minutes and its consequent command that will kill that stored PID. Since you sent this group of commands in background you do not stop your shell. You need to store the PID in a variable because the value of `$!` can be updated by an eventual execution of another program in background. In simple words you avoid the risk to *kill* the wrong process or no process at all.</sup>
- <sup>In the 6th version it is called a new bash shell that will suicide itself in 5 minutes via [`$$`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID), then it is executed your command that remains in foreground.</sup>
- <sup>In the 7th version it is invoked a subshell `()` that stores its PID in a variable (`cmdpid`) and kills itself with another subshell sent in background execution, then run YourCommand in foreground.</sup>

Of course in each version you can send the kill signal you need, from the default one to the *extreme* `kill -9`, to be  used only when really needed.

**References**

- [[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)] The Coreutils
- [[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)] The Bash Beginners Guide
- [[3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068)] The BashFAQ

Comment: "With sleep you can use your fantasy or take some inspirations [link to Bash FAQ]" +1 #thatsenoughinternetfortoday

Answer (score 11):

For your particular case, most implementations of `ping` support `-c` or `--count` to terminate after a particular number of pings:

```
ping -c 300 host.example.com
```

For a more general solution, see the other answers.

Comment: I get the impression OP just provided `ping` for a concrete example.  He doesn't want a case-by-case solution for every different program.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# $1 is the time to let the program run, and $2, $3, ... are the command itself.
#

"${@:2}" &
PID=$!
sleep "${@:1:1}"
kill -2 $PID
```

(signal SIGINT=2 used as per Matija Nalis' suggestion in the comment below).

An explanation of the (uncommon?) bash expression `$@:...`: the positional parameters, (`$*, $@, "$*", "$@"`) admit the following extra specification, for instance:

```
"${@:START:COUNT}"
```

which means: of all parameters, take COUNT of them, the first one to be taken being that at the STARTth position; if COUNT is omitted, take all of them till the end, beginning with the STARTth position. Remember that `$0` is the program name. If START is negative, start counting from the end, and remember that COUNT **cannot** be negative, hence the last argument is `"${@:-1}"`. Also, just about *always* include the positional parameters inside double quotes.

Comment: I'd probably design the script to take the time as the first or last arg, and run all the other args as the command.  Letting bash word-split `$1` is pretty gross.  Also, you could just `sleep "$1"` or something in `countdown`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Done, as per your wishes.

Comment: The time in first arg lets you do `time=$1; shift`, and then you don't need the array-slicing syntax for the positional parameters.  But yes, that's much simpler.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agreed, but you asked me to see whether I knew a safer way to do this and I had just been lazy, or whether I was just plain ignorant. lol.

Comment: as poster specifically asked about program that can be interrupted with `ctrl-c`, it is probably better to try `kill -INT` instead of `kill -9` (or at least try `-9` only after few seconds if the first one didn't suceed - it gives program chance to exit cleanly and not leave temporary files etc around)

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention `ping` in your example; this command has a few options to stop after a specific amount of time:

> - **w *deadline***   Specify a timeout, in seconds, before **ping** exits regardless of how many packets have been sent or received. In this case **ping** does not stop after *count* packet are sent, it waits either for *deadline* expire or until *count* probes are answered or for some error notification from network.
> - **W *timeout***   Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only timeout in absence of any responses, otherwise **ping** waits for two RTTs.
>
> —[`man ping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)